# Console.ReadKey breaks any effort to disable input to a service

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a console application written in C# that behaves like a service. When I start it, it starts all the necessary background threads and then wait for a keypress (by Console.ReadKey()) to terminate itself (and the background threads).

What I need is to be able to run (start) this service from a batch file (or command line) asynchronously without any possible interference from the keyboard input (which stops the service).

My first idea was to start this service from a batchfile in Windows on background using start /b service.exe. This works well, but inside the command line window, which was used to run the start command, if you press any key, the service immediately intercepts it and stops. That is even if you follow this async start call with a pause command, as soon as you press any key, the service will stop.

So I wanted to get around this by starting this service by start /b service.exe

So I tried to write my own C# wrapper which would redirect the input file using Process and ProcessStartInfo classes hoping it would be different. As soon as you redirect the input you get the same exception.

Is there any way I can "block" all input from reaching this service? I just want it to run in the background asynchronously whenever I run the batch script. It will be stopped by running different script. I cannot change the service itself. The reason why I need to run it asynchronously is because I have many such services and the batch file needs to start them all.

Comment: `yourservice.exe /no_key_abort` after adding code to look for that command line and updating your logic accordingly.

Comment: You should create a Windows Service application. In general they never interact with the desktop and you get all the goodies of Event logging in case of crash or auto-start on windows start etc.

Comment: Can you change the code in the service? If so, just add handling for a command-line parameter that you use to bypass the Console.ReadKey(). (Better would be to make it a service as suggested by Tallmaris)